# Variable within an another variable

Tags: css

Is it possible to let a property *variable* have a value of an another *variable*?

Like this:

```
:root {
    --theme-primary: --color-red;
    --color-red: #F44336;
}
```

... or:

```
:root {
    --theme-primary: var(--color-red);
    --color-red: #F44336;
}
```

If possible, what is the code, without using JS ***as possible***?

Comment: Since [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) are kind of new I'll just add a link for those who haven't heard of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible. In the following example the variable `--theme-primary` gets the value of `--color-yellow`. If it is not possible (the variable `--color-yellow` isn't defined or not valid) `--theme-primary` would be black (`#000`).

```css
:root {
  --theme-primary: var(--color-yellow, #000);
  --color-yellow: yellow;
  --color-blue: blue;
}
:root {
  --theme-secondary: var(--color-blue);
}
div {
  background: var(--theme-primary, green);
  border:5px dashed var(--theme-secondary, white);
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

You can also use a variable as fallback (second parameter of `val`). So you can do something like `var(--theme-primary, var(--theme-secondary, white));`

> **Additional links:**
>
> - *Browser support on Can I Use:*
>     http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables
> - *Using CSS variables on Mozilla Developer Network:*
>     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables
> - *Specification on W3C:*
>     https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/

Comment: My primary browser is Firefox, running the latest version, and I'm sure that all major browsers support that.

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm a little curious about what that "second value" in the `var()` was.  Is it the fallback value if something error goes with the variable?

Comment: @LloydDominic - that's right! If the first parameter fails, the second parameter take effect. And you see in the example above no fallback is used, so the first parameter is successfully used.

Comment: But, can it take for multiple parameters for multiple fallbacks, or just two parameters?

Comment: You can do something like this: `var(--theme-primary, var(--theme-secondary, white));`